# How to transform image to target image? Source image is dark gray, the target image has black, gray and white colors

Tags: opencv

The source image, it's result by gray converting from opencv.

```
cvtColor(img,COLOR_BGR2GRAY);
```

[image]

How I can convert this image to target:
[image]

Comment: [`cv::normalize`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga87eef7ee3970f86906d69a92cbf064bd) it.

Comment: @DanMašek I don't think normalizing is going to convert a right eye looking left to a left eye looking right!

Comment: Well, honestly I can barely see an eye on the first one, let alone any further details, so at the least that would be the first step. And probably a good idea to add the normalized image to the question.

Comment: I want to normalize only color of image, but I don't understand what is the parameters I must to go into "cv::normalize"

Comment: Use the `NORM_MINMAX` method, set `alpha` to 0 and `beta` to 255. That means that the darkest pixels will become completely black, the lightest will become completely while, and rest will be scaled/offset in a linear fashion to fill the range in bettween.

Answer (score 0):

[histogram equalization](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/imgproc/histograms/histogram_equalization/histogram_equalization.html) function can be used to distribute intensity values range equally.

[image]

```
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

/**  @function main */
int main( int argc, char** argv )
{
  Mat src, dst;

  char* source_window = "Source image";
  char* equalized_window = "Equalized Image";

  /// Load image
  src = imread( "path_to_image", CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE );

  /// Convert to grayscale
  //cvtColor( src, src, CV_BGR2GRAY );

  /// Apply Histogram Equalization
  equalizeHist( src, dst );

  /// Display results
  namedWindow( source_window, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
  namedWindow( equalized_window, CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );

  imshow( source_window, src );
  imshow( equalized_window, dst );

  /// Wait until user exits the program
  waitKey(0);

  return 0;
}
```